# Better way to count things?

Tags: c++, stl

In one of my programs for school, I use the following function to count the frequency of identifiers in a string, separated by newlines and #:

Input:

```
dog
cat
mouse
#
rabbit
snake
#
```

Function:

```
//assume I have the proper includes, and am using namespace std
vector< pair<string,int> > getFreqcounts(string input) {
    vector<string> items = splitString(input,"\n");
    map<string,int> counts;

    for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
        if (items[i] == "#") continue;
        counts[items[i]] = 0;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
        if (items[i] == "#") continue;
        counts[items[i]]++;
    }

    return vector< pair<string,int> > (counts.begin(),counts.end());
}
```

I would like to at the very least

- remove the double for loop
- find a better way to get a `vector< pair<string,int> >`

Any ideas?

BTW, this is NOT homework. The real homework will use this function, but this is purely out of my own curiosity and desire to have "better" code.

Comment: Is it required to use a `vector`? It seems much more logical to simply return the `map`.

Comment: The reason is that it will get passed to a sort function, which does not play nice with a map.

Comment: You could pass the keys of a `map` to a sort function.

Comment: @Alex: How so? I need to sort the keys of the map alphabetically to ouput to the console. I thought the point of `map` was to have arbitrarily ordered keys. Vectors on the other hand are ordered by index. Could you show me an example?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the STL, but isn't there any ordered map around?

Comment: As far as I know, no there isn't. But then I would not really be qualified to answer that myself...

Comment: map is ordered. You can add keys any way you like, but when you iterate over the entries using `counts.begin()` ... `counts.end()`, you will see them sorted by key.

Comment: @Steve, that's a good thing to keep in mind, and thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, the exercise is to implement a bubblesort, so I don't think I would get full credit for letting the STL do the heavy lifting...

Comment: Snorfle. In that case you may already be going too far by using a std::map: they might be expecting you to sort the lines first, and then once they're sorted run over the array counting how many there are of each.

Comment: Nah, my professor isn't too picky about that. If the problem is about using bubblesort, that's all he cares about since I've already proved I can do "simpler" things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the first for loop by simply deleting it. It accomplishes nothing useful. When/if the subscript into the map creates a new item, that item will have the chosen key, and your associated int will be initialized to zero automatically.

Personally, I'd probably do things a bit differently, using a stringstream instead of your `SplitString()`. I'm hesitant about posting code, but I guess I'll trust you...

```
typedef vector<pair<string, int> > count_vec;

count_vec GetFreqCounts(string const &input) { 
    istringstream in(input);
    string line;
    map<string, int> counts;

    while (getline(in, line))
        if (line != "#")
            ++counts[line];
    return count_vec(counts.begin(), counts.end());
}
```

Edit: I honestly didn't pay a whole lot of attention to efficiency as I was writing this, but I think Steve Jessop's comment on it is pretty accurate. As long as the input is small, it won't make any real difference. If the input is really big, the fact that this only uses an extra copy of one word at a time could save enough memory to be meaningful.

The solution Steve gave in his reply looks pretty nice too though. Since it also processes words as they're produced, I'd expect it to have characteristics *similar* to the code above. If you can break the string into words faster than `stringstream` does, it'll undoubtedly be faster. Given the number of virtual functions that get in the way with iostreams, there's a pretty good chance of that -- but unless you're dealing with a lot of text there's not much chance of it making a significant difference. Of course, exactly what qualifies as significant is open to question. To put it in perspective, I ran some similar code across a word list I had handy. Using code pretty close to what's above, it processes text at a little over 10 megabytes a second.

Comment: That works too. Would this be any more efficient than what I have? `splitString()` just walks through the string taking substrings as it goes. And don't worry, I'm not going to just copy and paste this. My opinions on homework questions should be evident from my other homework-related q's & a's, if you care to look :)

Comment: It probably will be more efficient, yes. The reason is that your splitStrings constructs a honking great vector of strings, then goes back to the beginning and walks over it again. Jerry uses each string immediately, as soon as it's constructed. So it uses less memory, and for significant amounts of data Jerry's version should provoke fewer cache misses. Against that, `stringstream::getline()` may or may not be faster than whatever you're doing in splitString.

Comment: Also, taking input by reference will prevent a copy of it, but istringstream then copies it anyway. So modifying splitString to take a const reference might be fastest of all. Especially if you also modify splitString to take a functor specifying what to do with each line it finds, rather than returning the lines. You can then specify this functor to increment the count. Whether you should care sort of depends how big your input is likely to be - copying 2k of data is probably nothing. Copying 2GB kind of matters.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding of `std::map` is such that the entire first loop can simply be eliminated. The first time you try to access a node that does not exist the `map` will default-create it for you, setting the initial count to zero (the default-ctor behavior of a builtin type.) That should be all the changes you need to make to your code, and the behavior should be the same.

**Update:** On a side note in the code you have provided `counts` will be sorted according to `operator<` defined for `std::string` (the key type for your map), which will sort the `map` nodes lexicographically. There's no need to pump the results through a vector and sort the vector - the map is handling this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to Jerry's answer I mentioned using a functor. Here's the sort of thing I mean (untested code):

```
struct StringCounter {
    std::map<std::string, int> counts;
    void operator()(const std::string &s) {
        ++counts[s];
    }
};

template <typename Output>
void splitString(const string &input, const string &separator, Output &out) {
    // do whatever you currently do to get each string, call it "s"...
    out(s);
    // lather, rinse, repeat
}

vector< pair<string,int> > getFreqcounts(const string &input) {
    StringCounter sc;
    splitString(input,"\n",sc);
    return vector< pair<string,int> > (sc.counts.begin(),sc.counts.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current logic but contain all of it in a single loop, you can use find(), like so:

```
map<string,int> counts;
loop on curr ..
map<string,int>::iterator it = counts.find(curr);
if (it != counts.end())
  ++it->second;
else
  counts[curr] = 1;
```

But that's not what I would do. There's no need to explicitly initialize the map entry in the first time as it will default to zero anyway, so you can use:

```
map<string,int> counts;
loop on curr ..
  if (..
    ++map[curr];
```

Another thing i would do is use [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) with '\n' and '#' being the delimiters.